# How to deduce that there doesn't exist any sequence of polynomials $P_n$ such that $P_n(z)\to \frac 1z$

Tags: complex-analysis, sequence-of-function, entire-functions

The exercise I have reads as follow:

> 1. Let $f$ be an entire function. Compute
>    \begin{equation}
>    \frac1{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{1-zf(z)}{z}dz
>    \end{equation}
> 2. Prove that all $f$ entire functions verify that
>    \begin{equation}
>    \max_{|z|=1}|z^{-1}-f(z)|\ge1
>    \end{equation}
>    Deduce that there doesn't exist any sequence of polynomials $P_n$ such that $P_n\to\frac1z$, uniformly in $\{|z|=1\}$.

I know that 1. can be done with $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1-zf(z)}{z} = \frac{1}z-f(z)
\end{equation}
So
\begin{equation}
\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{1-zf(z)}{z}dz = \frac1{2\pi i}\left(\int_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{z}dz - \int_{|z|=1}f(z)dz\right) = \frac1{2\pi i}(2\pi i-0) = 1
\end{equation}

The second exercise is also simple enough, since we got the following:

\begin{equation}
1 = \left| \frac1{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{1-zf(z)}{z}dz \right|\le \frac1{2\pi} \operatorname{len}(\{|z|=1\})\max_{|z|=1}|g(z)|\le \frac1{2\pi}2\pi\max_{|z|=1}\left|\frac{1-zf(z)}{z}\right| = \max_{|z|=1}\left|\frac{1}{z}-f(z)\right|
\end{equation}

But how do I deduce from this that there doesn't exist a sequence of polynomials $P_n$ such that $P_n\to\frac1z$ uniformly in $\{|z|=1\}$?

Comment: hint: every polynomial is an entire function, now use 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Since every polynomial is an entire function you would have $$\lVert z^{-1}-P_n(z)\rVert_\infty \to 0$$
in $|z|=1$. Do you see the contradiction?

**Full solution:** Suppose such sequence of polynomials existed. Then you would have
$$\lVert z^{-1}-P_n(z)\rVert_\infty \to 0$$
But from 2. for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $z\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|z|=1$ you would have
$$\lVert z^{-1}-P_n(z)\rVert_\infty \geq 1$$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: That is what I can't see. As Masacroso and you say, $P_n$ is entire, but I don't know how to use 2. in order to see that $|z^{-1}-P_n|\to0$ isn't possible.

Comment: @GreekCorpse I have given the full solution. See my edited answer.

Comment: Oh, so you just use 2. directly. I see now. Thank you for answering!

Comment: @GreekCorpse Happy to have helpled!

Comment: I just had a hard time figuring out that $|z^{-1}-P_n(z)|\ge 1$ when it was only established in its maximum.

Comment: @GreekCorpse That's why uniform convergence is stronger.